# Android Studio Corner Radius / Elevation and Shadow Color

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I wonder how is it possible to make an elevation of a CardView / or EditText in android Studio like the picture below - with the same color for the shadow (I'm searching for the same result) [elevation and cornerRadius](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9gqw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following dependency to the build.gradle file.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

Add the following code to your xml file to create a MaterialCardView. Modify the values of `cardCornerRadius` and `cardElevation` till you get desired result.

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            ...
            app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            app:cardElevation="10dp"
            ...
            >

            ...


</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

As for shadow, there is no implicit support within the framework to change the shadow color.

Check out this [Twitter thread](https://twitter.com/crafty/status/1011918657759469569) by Nick Butcher where shares a [prototype implementation](https://gist.github.com/nickbutcher/1dcde5a989011d01fda491bc9a59c21e) to achieve something similar. He has also mentioned that it is doubtful that the feature will be added to the support library.

Comment: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #91: Binary XML file line #91: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView. BUT NOT ERROR WHEN USING "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0". However, the result is not like the picture

Comment: Well, I have shared with you the way to create a MaterialCardView. It's up to you now to modify the attributes accordingly to get the result you want.

Comment: Thank you sats, i'm just looking to change the color of the Shadow, like I writed in the question, i keep getting the dark shadow color, how can i do it ????

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/view"/>
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/_90sdp"
     />
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:left="@dimen/_1sdp"
    android:right="@dimen/_40sdp"
    android:top="@dimen/_1sdp"
    android:bottom="@dimen/_40sdp"
>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/_90sdp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```